# How to disable the sign up page once user gets inside the app?

Tags: iphone

In my application there is a login page after login the user will get access to the functionalities of the application.

Now there is a back button clicking on which the user will go on to the home page now my requirement is that when the user returns to the home page it sholud not ask for the login again that is the login page should be disabled it should directly go on to the next page.

How to do that???

Please help me.......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check to see if the user is logged in. If not, present the login view modally, if the user is logged in, skip that step.

Comment: that i know. but user cat get frested doing login agian and agian

Comment: Add an option to "Remember Login"